# Is adding a notice directed to the question poster acceptable when the notice doesn't improve the question?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

I just came upon a notice, for lack of a better word, added to the bottom of a question by a high-rep user.  The notice in question is directed to the question author, and is telling them that the high-rep user made the question into a runnable stack-snippet, and to uncomment specific lines that they commented in order to make the snippet runnable.

It feels to me that since this information doesn't improve the question, that it should be in a comment, but the information being added by a high-rep user is making me second-guess that thought.

To clarify, the 'high-rep' of the user in question is 14k, and I haven't linked the Question in question as I don't want the meta effect to occur.

That said, is the proper response to flag, leave it as is, or something else?

The notice in question:

[image: Screen shot of notice]

**Update:** During the period of this meta question, the notice in question was removed by the one who added it, after someone else asked them about it.  In hindsight, I likely should have done the same, but moments in the past have me apprehensive about doing things like that.

Comment: Nope, this should be edited out *unless* the user is repeating something has mentioned elsewhere. A *notice* addressed to the OP is what **comments** are for....not question edits.

Comment: From what I can tell, the user is not repeating anything mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: I've seen plenty of high-rep users make some questionable decisions, so don't let that sway your interpretation of the situation. Based on the information given, it definitely sounds inappropriate.

Comment: well, we need to see the question to judge. Don't worry about the meta effect ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif As it turns out, during the period in which this meta question existed, someone brought up the point this meta question is based off of, and the high-rep user in question fixed the Question in question in order to remove the notice.  In hindsight, I likely should have done the same(ask them about it), but frankly I've had moments in the past where commenting to that effect didn't result in anything good on my end.  That said, will an image of the notice in question suffice with names scrubbed off of it?

Comment: anything that could give us more information would be good, even a screenshot

Comment: @TemaniAfif Added a screen shot of the notice in question.

Comment: Looks like an "Attempt to reply" edit by a >2k user.  Edit it out.  Flag if there's a pattern or user begins an edit war.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I'm making a questionable decision right now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding any text that is not related to the question is not appropriate. That includes "thank you", "hello", "EDITED:"/"UPDATE:", as well as the text shown in this question. Such unrelated text can be removed by any member of community without need to talk to the OP or the editor who added the extra text.

After the extra text is edited out there is no need for any additional action (like flagging/downvoting) unless you know that this particular editor does it frequently. In later case make sure to provide links to edits showing the behavior in the explanation text of the "need moderator intervention" flag.

The notice shown in this question would be reasonable as comment under the post. Alternatively if one feels that a long description like that is needed there is a good chance that the edit is *too extensive* and should not be done in the first place.

Comment: Though the notice added important notes about uncommenting the parts they did comment which are very relevant to future readers. Having this in the comment section wouldn't be a good usage of comments either. The best action here from editor would have been to make the whole code with localStorage part (i.e non runnable), a code block, and make a collapsed runnable snippet with their edits.

Comment: @Kaiido possible. I don't know if whatever was commented out is actually relevant to the question - there is a good chance that it was only useful to OP and any future visitor actually would not need that... Or indeed second runnable version would be more appropriate.

Comment: The author should have made sure, the code they provided the community could be compiled, then the community is not fixing syntax errors for somebody.